# Why do I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python, compiler-errors, typeerror

I have been trying to run this code below for weeks, but still got this same error. There are two files. The first one is phog code which have no error and I tried to import it into the second file. The second file is the one that I got this Type error.

This is the code I tried to run (2nd file : have error) :

```
# Importing the necessary modules:
from skimage.feature import hog, local_binary_pattern
from skimage.transform import pyramid_gaussian
from skimage.io import imread
import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from skimage import color
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import imutils
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio
from ipynb.fs.full.anna_phog import anna_phog
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import glob
from sklearn import metrics
from PIL import Image # This will be used to read/modify images (can be done via OpenCV too)
from numpy import *

S = 8
angle = 360
Level = 3
roi = [1,225,1,300]
save=True

image_path = r"C:\Users\user\Documents\FYP\train"

# read the image files:
category_im_listing = os.listdir(image_path) # it will read all the files in the path
num_category_im = size(category_im_listing) # simply states the total no. of category
print("There are " + str(num_category_im) + " categories") # prints the number value of the no.of categories dataset
data= []
labels = []
count = 0

# compute HOG features and label them:
for category in category_im_listing: #this loop enables reading the files in the pos_im_listing variable one by one
    im_listing = os.listdir(image_path + "/" + category)
    num_im = size(im_listing)
    print("There are " + str(num_im) + " images in category " + str(count + 1))
    for file in im_listing:
        img=cv2.imread(image_path + "/" + category + "/" + file) # open the file
        # calculate HOG for positive features
        p = anna_phog(img, bin, angle, Level, roi) # p= feature descriptor
        data.append(p)
        labels.append(count)
    count = count + 1
```

This is the error that I got after I run the code above :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3efb469c7910> in <module>
      8         img=cv2.imread(image_path + "/" + category + "/" + file) # open the file
      9         # calculate HOG for positive features
---> 10         fd = anna_phog(img, bin, angle, Level, roi)# fd= feature descriptor
     11         data.append(fd)
     12         labels.append(count)

~\Desktop\FYP\anna_phog.ipynb in anna_phog(Img, bin, angle, L, roi)
     35     "        E = cv2.Canny(G,lower,upper) #high and low treshold\n",
     36     "        GradientX, GradientY = np.gradient(G)\n",
---> 37     "        GradientYY = np.gradient(GradientY, axis=1)\n",
     38     "        \n",
     39     "        Gr = np.sqrt(np.square(GradientX)+np.square(GradientY))\n",

~\Desktop\FYP\anna_phog.ipynb in anna_BinMatrix(A, E, G, angle, bin)
     56     "    p = anna_PhogDescriptor(bh_roi,bv_roi,L,bin)\n",
     57     "    return p"
---> 58    ]
     59   },
     60   {

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

1st file : No error (I actually think the error is from here, but not sure where should I change):

```
import numpy as np
import imageio
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def anna_phog(Img, bin, angle, L, roi):
    '''
     anna_PHOG Computes Pyramid Histogram of Oriented Gradient over a ROI.

     [BH, BV] = anna_PHOG(Img,BIN,ANGLE,L,ROI) computes phog descriptor over a ROI.

     Given and image Img, phog computes the Pyramid Histogram of Oriented Gradients
     over L pyramid levels and over a Region Of Interest

    IN:
        Img- Images numpy array of size MxN (Color or Gray)
        bin - Number of bins on the histogram
        angle - 180 or 360
       L - number of pyramid levels
       roi - Region Of Interest (ytop,ybottom,xleft,xright)

    OUT:
        p - pyramid histogram of oriented gradients
    '''
    if Img.shape[2] == 3:
        G = cv2.cvtColor(Img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
        G = Img

    if np.sum(G) > 100:
        # apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
        sigma = 0.33
        v = np.median(G)
        lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
        upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
        E = cv2.Canny(G,lower,upper) #high and low treshold
        GradientX, GradientY = np.gradient(G)
        GradientYY = np.gradient(GradientY, axis=1)

        Gr = np.sqrt(np.square(GradientX)+np.square(GradientY))
        index = GradientX == 0
        GradientX[index] = 1e-5 #maybe another value

        YX = GradientY*GradientX
        if angle == 180: A = ((np.arctan(YX)+(np.pi/2))*180)/np.pi
        if angle == 360: A = ((np.arctan2(GradientY,GradientX)+np.pi)*180)/np.pi

        bh, bv = anna_BinMatrix(A,E,Gr,angle,bin)

    else:
        bh = np.zeros(Img.shape)
        bv = np.zeros(Img.shape)

    bh_roi = bh[roi[0]:roi[1], roi[2]:roi[3]]
    bv_roi = bv[roi[0]:roi[1], roi[2]:roi[3]]

    p = anna_PhogDescriptor(bh_roi,bv_roi,L,bin)
    return p


def anna_BinMatrix(A,E,G,angle,bin):
    '''
    anna_BINMATRIX Computes a Matrix (bm) with the same size of the image where
    (i,j) position contains the histogram value for the pixel at position (i,j)
    and another matrix (bv) where the position (i,j) contains the gradient
    value for the pixel at position (i,j)

    IN:
        A - Matrix containing the angle values
        E - Edge Image
        G - Matrix containing the gradient values
        angle - 180 or 360
        bin - Number of bins on the histogram

    OUT:
        bm - matrix with the histogram values
        bv - matrix with the gradient values (only for the pixels belonging to and edge)
    '''
    n, contorns = cv2.connectedComponents(E, connectivity=8)

    X = E.shape[1]
    Y = E.shape[0]
    bm = np.zeros(shape=(Y,X))
    bv = np.zeros(shape=(Y,X))

    nAngle = angle/bin

    for i in range(n):
        posY, posX = np.where(contorns==i)
        for j in range(posY.shape[0]):
            pos_x = posX[j]
            pos_y = posY[j]

            b = np.ceil(A[pos_y,pos_x]/nAngle)
            if b==0: bin=1
            if G[pos_y,pos_x]>0:
                bm[pos_y,pos_x] = b
                bv[pos_y,pos_x] = G[pos_y,pos_x]

    return (bm, bv)



def anna_PhogDescriptor(bh,bv,L,bin):
    '''
     anna_PHOGDESCRIPTOR Computes Pyramid Histogram of Oriented Gradient over a ROI.

    IN:
        bh - matrix of bin histogram values
        bv - matrix of gradient values
       L - number of pyramid levels
       bin - number of bins

    OUT:
        p - pyramid histogram of oriented gradients (phog descriptor)
    '''
    p = np.array([])
    #level 0
    for b in range(bin):
        ind = bh==b
        p = np.append(p, np.sum(bv[ind]))

    #higher levels
    for l in range(1, L+1):
        x = int(np.trunc(bh.shape[1]/(2**l)))
        y = int(np.trunc(bh.shape[0]/(2**l)))
        for xx in range(0, bh.shape[1]-x+1, x):
            for yy in range(0, bh.shape[0]-y+1, y):
                print(l)
                bh_cella = bh[yy:yy+y, xx:xx+x]
                bv_cella = bv[yy:yy+y, xx:xx+x]

                for b in range(bin):
                    ind = bh_cella==b
                    p = np.append(p, np.sum(bv_cella[ind], axis=0))

    if np.sum(p)!=0:
        p = p/np.sum(p)

    return p
```

Comment: `bin` is a built-in function. I think you mean something else in `anna_phog(img, bin, angle, Level, roi)`. What are you wanting `bin` to be there?

Comment: Yet another reason why shadowing builtins is bad. You never assigned a value to `bin`, so its still the builtin function `bin`. To fix this, the recommended solution is to rename your variable to something else (and then make sure you assign a value to it).